# Apollo / Graphcool Subscriptions - WebSocket is closed before the connection is established

Tags: apollo, graphcool

I'm trying to set up a graphcool subscription / websockets as per this tutorial at [How To GraphQL](https://www.howtographql.com/react-apollo/8-subscriptions/) but I'm getting the following message:

> WebSocket connection to
>   'wss://subscriptions.graph.cool/v1/###' failed:
>   WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

I'm seem to have everything as per the tutorial. Do you have any idea why the websockets connection is not being established?

---

index.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './components/App'
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker'
import './styles/index.css'
import { ApolloProvider, createNetworkInterface, ApolloClient } from 'react-apollo'
import { SubscriptionClient, addGraphQLSubscriptions } from 'subscriptions-transport-ws'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { GC_AUTH_TOKEN } from './constants'

const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({
  uri: 'https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/###'
})

const wsClient = new SubscriptionClient('wss://subscriptions.graph.cool/v1/###', {
  reconnect: true,
  connectionParams: {
     authToken: localStorage.getItem(GC_AUTH_TOKEN),
  }
})

const networkInterfaceWithSubscriptions = addGraphQLSubscriptions(
  networkInterface,
  wsClient
)

networkInterface.use([{
  applyMiddleware(req, next) {
    if (!req.options.headers) {
      req.options.headers = {}
    }
    const token = localStorage.getItem(GC_AUTH_TOKEN)
    req.options.headers.authorization = token ? `Bearer ${token}` : null
    next()
  }
}])

const client = new ApolloClient({
  networkInterface: networkInterfaceWithSubscriptions
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <App />
    </ApolloProvider>
  </BrowserRouter>
  , document.getElementById('root')
)
registerServiceWorker()
```

App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import LinkList from './LinkList'
import CreateLink from './CreateLink'
import Header from './Header'
import Login from './Login'
import Search from './Search'
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='center w85'>
        <Header />
        <div className='ph3 pv1 background-gray'>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/search' component={Search}/>
            <Route exact path='/' component={LinkList}/>
            <Route exact path='/create' component={CreateLink}/>
            <Route exact path='/login' component={Login}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

LinkList.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Link from './Link'
import { graphql, gql } from 'react-apollo'

class LinkList extends Component {

  _updateCacheAfterVote = (store, createVote, linkId) => {
    const data = store.readQuery({ query: ALL_LINKS_QUERY })

    const votedLink = data.allLinks.find(link => link.id === linkId)
    votedLink.votes = createVote.link.votes

    store.writeQuery({ query: ALL_LINKS_QUERY, data })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._subscribeToNewLinks()
    this._subscribeToNewVotes()
  }


  render() {

    if (this.props.allLinksQuery && this.props.allLinksQuery.loading) {
      return <div>Loading</div>
    }

    if (this.props.allLinksQuery && this.props.allLinksQuery.error) {
      return <div>Error</div>
    }

    const linksToRender = this.props.allLinksQuery.allLinks

    return (
      <div>
      {linksToRender.map((link, index) => (
        <Link key={link.id} updateStoreAfterVote={this._updateCacheAfterVote}  index={index} link={link}/>
      ))}
      </div>
    )
  }

  _subscribeToNewLinks = () => {
    this.props.allLinksQuery.subscribeToMore({
      document: gql`
        subscription {
          Link(filter: {
            mutation_in: [CREATED]
          }) {
            node {
              id
              url
              description
              createdAt
              postedBy {
                id
                name
              }
              votes {
                id
                user {
                  id
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `,
      updateQuery: (previous, { subscriptionData }) => {
        const newAllLinks = [
          subscriptionData.data.Link.node,
          ...previous.allLinks
        ]
        const result = {
          ...previous,
          allLinks: newAllLinks
        }
        return result
      }
    })
  }

  _subscribeToNewVotes = () => {
    this.props.allLinksQuery.subscribeToMore({
      document: gql`
        subscription {
          Vote(filter: {
            mutation_in: [CREATED]
          }) {
            node {
              id
              link {
                id
                url
                description
                createdAt
                postedBy {
                  id
                  name
                }
                votes {
                  id
                  user {
                    id
                  }
                }
              }
              user {
                id
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `,
      updateQuery: (previous, { subscriptionData }) => {
        const votedLinkIndex = previous.allLinks.findIndex(link => link.id === subscriptionData.data.Vote.node.link.id)
        const link = subscriptionData.data.Vote.node.link
        const newAllLinks = previous.allLinks.slice()
        newAllLinks[votedLinkIndex] = link
        const result = {
          ...previous,
          allLinks: newAllLinks
        }
        return result
      }
    })
  }

}

export const ALL_LINKS_QUERY = gql`
  query AllLinksQuery {
    allLinks {
      id
      createdAt
      url
      description
      postedBy {
        id
        name
      }
      votes {
        id
        user {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

export default graphql(ALL_LINKS_QUERY, { name: 'allLinksQuery' }) (LinkList)
```

Comment: I guess the error is on the server. How is the connection established?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. How do I figure that out?
I just run yarn start & apollo does it's magic based on index.js above and graphcool handles server side. All I really have is the endpoint they've provided.

Comment: Is the `<project-id>` correct, which you get from the graph.cool endpoint. In the tutorial it is under the point "Now update the configuration code like so:"

Comment: Yes triple checked it.

Comment: ok, you could add the `connectionCallback: (error) => {}` in the SubscriptionClient. Maybe it gives you a better error. Else i do not know how to fix this

Comment: Nope, nothing. Even tried setting up a new graph.cool project. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the websocket endpoint was incorrect and is different for the Asia Pacific region `wss://subscriptions.ap-northeast-1.graph.cool/v1/###`

Comment: It seems there is a bug of graphql-playground. I had submitted an issue to https://github.com/graphcool/graphql-playground/issues/591

Answer (score 6):

Can you add the `timeout` parameter to your client configuration like this:

```
const wsClient = new SubscriptionClient('wss://subscriptions.graph.cool/v1/###', {
  reconnect: true,
  timeout: 30000,
  connectionParams: {
     authToken: localStorage.getItem(GC_AUTH_TOKEN),
  }
})
```

There's a slight mismatch between the `subscription-transport-ws` client implementation and the Graphcool subscription server implementation how keep-alives are handled, and the long timeout period fixes it.

Read [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws/issues/220) and [this Graphcool feature request](https://github.com/graphcool/feature-requests/issues/309#issuecomment-314761299) for more background information.

Comment: Still the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: what's your version of `subscription-transport-ws`?

Comment: `subscriptions-transport-ws@0.8.1`

Comment: Thanks, looks like `0.8.2` is required as per [your conversation on GitHub](https://github.com/howtographql/react-apollo/issues/2)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using `wss://domain.com/graphql` whereas my websocket server was not secure so I had to change it to `ws://domain.com/graphql`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix mine using the `lazy: true` option.

```js
reconnect: true,
lazy: true, // <--- This
connectionParams: {
  // ...
},
```

[Source](https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/4509#issuecomment-759838030)